# cannot externally connect to my Node.Js server? (DUPLICATE)

Tags: node.js, server

server:

```
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')

//404
function _404(response) {
    response.writeHead(404, {'Context-Type': 'text/plain'})
    response.write('error 404, not found')
    response.end()
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080)
console.log('server is running')

function onRequest(request, response) {
    if (request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/') {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Context-Type': 'text/html'})
        fs.createReadStream('./testhtml.html').pipe(response)
    } else {
        _404(response)      
    }
}
```

works fine when i enter into my browser and call with localhost:8080, but am trying to connect to it with my phone (not on this network connection, but 4G) by entering my ip and port (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080)

Why is this not working, am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from another question [duplicate]:

Don't forgot to forward your port through router settings cause the router is receiving the requests not your PC

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080, "0.0.0.0")
```

because otherwise you can listen only to localhost interface.

Also it would be good to replace `Context-Type` with `Content-Type`.